# Hours, Minutes selector widget

Tags: android

I am porting one of my iOS apps over to android, and one of the layouts uses the `UIDatePicker` with the mode `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer`.  I have searched and searched and searched for something even close in android, and the only thing I have come across is the `TimePicker` widget which only seems to do time of day.

Does something like `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer` exist in android, or do I have to fenagle my own solution for entering this type of time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one stop shop that includes a date picker and a time picker, both are seperate

so basically you need a date field that shows a [DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) and a time field that show a [TimePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html) when clicked

Comment: It has to come up as a separate dialog?  I'd really rather have it be embedded in the view.  I don't care if they are separate things (time and duration), just as long as it is in the view

Comment: Yes they are 2 separate dialogs. If you need something else then you have to create a custom `DatePickerDialog` but it will be easier just to use 2 separate dialogs

Comment: The `TimePickerDialog` documentation states that it prompts the user for "the time of day", this includes an am/pm indication.  Is there something like the count down timer in iOS that just allows you to select a number of hours and a number of minutes.  It really just selects a duration, not a time.

Comment: I think I am confused now, you want something that just displays hours and minuets with no AM/PM?

Comment: Yes, I want something to select a number of hours and a number of minutes, like the `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer`.  I am not trying to select a time of day, I am trying to enter a duration of time

Comment: Then you will have to create a view with 2 `NumberPickers` in them, then create an array of hours and an array of minutes to put in the picker. Or you can set the max number and the min number of the picker too. Doing that will give you want you want

Comment: Hm, I guess a pair of numberpickers is the solution, not sure why those aren't showing up in my widget library in eclipse though

Comment: NumberPicker is under the advanced folder in the layout editor

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you will either need a 3rd party library or you will need to create a custom version of the TimePicker.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :**
Basically i've done something similar like your requirement, i have a time picker dialog in dialog fragment, without am/pm indicator. You only have to set the DateFormat to 24 hour format in onCreateDialog method. Something similar like this :

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker

    int hour = 0;
    int minute = 0;

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog without am/pm and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}
```

I hope this answer help you :)

Comment: I'd be a little wary of using that, given how much of a direct copy of Apple's design that is

Comment: You didn' mention that requirement. Please take a look at my updated answer.